# Installing Redhat Satellite server

Tags: linux, redhat

I was wondering if anybody can share some installation steps on Redhat Satellite server. I tried to look at Google but couldn't find relevant.

It would be really great help.

Thanks in advance,
Suman

Answer (score 1):

Really? "redhat satellite server installation" query in Google yields a metric ton of results, including: [Official RedHat Installation Guide](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Network_Satellite/5.0/pdf/Installation_Guide/Red_Hat_Network_Satellite-5.0-Installation_Guide-en-US.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

The command to register a RHEL system with RHN is:

```
rhn_register
```

•   After the system is registered with RHN, you should fully update the system and reboot before attempting to install Satellite.

•   To update a RHEL system with all current updates:

```
yum -y update
```

•   Update HOSTNAME in /etc/sysconfig/network with the xxx.xxx.

•   Configure IPTables to allow inbound TCP ports 80, 443, and 5222.

•   Restart the IPTables service.

•   Configure IPTables to allow inbound TCP ports 80, 443, and 5222.
o   Add the following to /etc/sysconfig/iptables after the line with “dport 22”:

```
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 5222 -j ACCEPT
```

•   Restart the IPTables service.

```
 serviceiptables restart
```

•   Mount the satellite ISO in root’s home directory to /mnt:

```
 mount -o loop /setupfiles/satellite-5.5.0-20120911-rhel-6-x86_64.iso /mnt

 cd /mnt

./install.pl --disconnected
rhn-satellite start
```

Done